# Python 3 разбиение текста на фрагменты

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

Есть большой текст ~ 400000 символов, который считывается из .txt файла и его нужно разбить над тексты меньше размером до ~ 9100 символов + данные фрагменты должны заканчиваться точкой. Пока что придумал решение только через str.split("."), а затем в каждом предложении считать количество символов и когда счетчик приблизится к 9100 находить ближайшую точку и обрезать выделенный фрагмент и продолжать процесс. Существуют ли какие нибудь библиотеки, которые могли бы упростить данный процесс?

Comment: Опубликуйте пример вашего решения.

Comment: https://repl.it/@shardakov/MediumVelvetyCone-1

Пока что смог додуматься только до этого

Comment: А если в тексте точка используется не в качестве конца предложения? Например: дробные числа, Фамилия И.О., многоточие.

Comment: Я думал на счет этого, но пока что ни чего дельного в голову не пришло. Так как делал это только для перевода одной книги и тест на ней прошел, то сейчас буду думать, как улучшить код.

Comment: Возможно, что-то подобное уже реализовано в инструментах токенизации языка - [NTLK](https://www.nltk.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте мой пример. Напишите, что получилось :)

```
from textwrap import wrap                   #   <---

text_input  = '1.txt'
with open(text_input, 'r') as f1:
    lines = f1.read() 

listWrap = wrap(lines, width=9000)

text_output = '2.txt'
with open(text_output, 'w') as f2:   

    moveTextToNewLine = ''

    for line in listWrap:
        point = max(line.rfind(". "), line.rfind("! "), line.rfind("? "))

        if point == -1:
            moveTextToNewLine = moveTextToNewLine + line
        else:
            newLine = "{}{}\n".format(moveTextToNewLine, line[0:point+1])
            f2.write( newLine ) 
            moveTextToNewLine = line[point+2:] + " "

    f2.write(moveTextToNewLine + "\n")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ваше решение выполняет поставленную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Суть выдуманной мной задачи была в том, чтобы скармливать части текста в яндекс переводчик, но так как он принимает только 10000 символов за раз, нужно было разделить текст на маленькие подтексты. В итоге я получил что-то подобное, но нужно будет еще несколько подправить итоговый вариант.

```
import requests

URL = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate" 
# Your api key
KEY = "trnsl.1.1.20190429T065522Z.18f4830c20ee2f4b.b940037513ea0a3e99dd7129948c0a456985e3d6b"

text_input = r'1.txt'
text_output = r'2.txt'
text_ru = r'3.txt'

def rep_pdf_to_txt(text_in, text_out):
  with open(text_input, 'r') as f1, open(text_output, 'w') as f2:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if(line.endswith(".\n")):
            f2.write(line + "\n")
        else:
            f2.write(line.replace("\n", " ") + " ")

def split_text(text_out):
  with open(text_output, 'r') as f2:
    tmp_text = f2.read()
    tmp = tmp_text.split(".")
    n = 0
    tmp_str = ""
    tmp_list = []
    for str in tmp:
      n += len(str)
      tmp_str += str + "."
      if(n > 9000):  
        tmp_list.append(tmp_str)
        tmp_str = ""
        n = 0
    return tmp_list

def translate(my_text):
  params = {
    "key": KEY,
    "text": my_text,    
    "lang": 'en-ru'
  }
  response = requests.get(URL, params = params)
  json_response = response.json()
  return json_response

# input parameters
'''
my_text = "Test params for my text input for translate"
json = translate(my_text)
print(''.join(json["text"]))
'''
rep_pdf_to_txt(text_input, text_output)
t_list = split_text(text_output)
with open(text_ru, 'w') as f3:
  for i in t_list:
    f3.write(''.join(translate(i)["text"]))
    f3.write("\n Переведено сервисом «Яндекс.Переводчик»  http://translate.yandex.ru/ \n")
```

Comment: `Переведено сервисом «Яндекс.Переводчик»` а это зачем добавлять? :)

Comment: Требование яндекса к оформлению перевода 
https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/concepts/design-requirements-docpage/
Хотя, я облажался, нужно переместить эту строку

Comment: Ого, спасибо :) хотя бы их сервисом можно без api-key пользоваться и на том спасибо :D

Answer (score 0):

Если принять, что всегда можно задачу выполнить (т.е. нет слишком длинного  фрагмента без точек):

```
s = 'abc.d.ef.g.ij.klmn.op.rq.a.tu.vwx.yz.'
sz = 5
lastpoint = -1
start = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == '.':
        lastpoint = i
    if i - start >= sz:
        print(s[start:lastpoint+1])
        start = lastpoint + 1
if start < len(s):
    print(s[start:len(s)])

abc.d.
ef.g.
ij.
klmn.
op.rq.
a.tu.
vwx.
yz.
```

для sz=7:

```
abc.d.
ef.g.ij.
klmn.op.
rq.a.tu.
vwx.yz.
```